# C# - Interface -Help in power of Interface

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. Recently I have read an article.It suggests

*"One of the practical uses of interface is, when an interface reference is created that can*

work on different kinds of objects which implements that interface."

*Base on that  I tested (I am not sure my understanding is correct)*

```
 namespace InterfaceExample

 {
public interface IRide

{

  void Ride();

}

abstract class Animal

{
  private string _classification;

  public string Classification
  {
   set { _classification = value;}
   get { return _classification;}
  }

  public Animal(){}

  public Animal(string _classification)
  {
    this._classification = _classification;
  }

}

class Elephant:Animal,IRide

{

  public Elephant(){}

   public Elephant(string _majorClass):base(_majorClass)
   {
   }


  public void Ride()

  {

   Console.WriteLine("Elephant can ride 34KPM");

  }

}

class Horse:Animal,IRide

{
   public Horse(){}

   public Horse(string _majorClass):base(_majorClass)
   {

   }



    public void Ride()

    {
      Console.WriteLine("Horse can ride 110 KPH");
    }

}


class Test

{
    static void Main()

    {
       Elephant bully = new Elephant("Vertebrata");
       Horse    lina  = new Horse("Vertebrata");
       IRide[] riders = {bully,lina};

       foreach(IRide rider in riders)
       {

         rider.Ride();
       }

               Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
} 

}
```

---

Questions :

Beyond such extend, what are the different way can we leverage the elegance of Interfaces ?

What is the Key point that I can say this can be only done by interface (apart from

multiple inheritances) ?

(I wish to gather the information from experienced hands).

Edit :

Edited to be concept centric,i guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because C# doesn't support multiple inheritance (which is a good thing IMHO) interfaces are the way you specify shared behavior or state across otherwise unrelated types.

```
interface IRideable
{
    void Ride();
}

class Elephant : Animal, IRideable{}

class Unicycle: Machine, IRideable{}
```

In this manner, say you had a program that modeled a circus (where machines and animals had distinct behavior, but some machines and some animals could be ridden) you can create abstract functionality specific to what is means to ride something.

```
public static void RideThemAll(IEnumerable<IRideable> thingsToRide)
{
  foreach(IRideable rideable in thingsToRide)
     ridable.Ride();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The point is, you could also have a class `Bike` which implements `IRide`, without inheriting from Animal. You can think of an interface as being an abstract contract, specifying that objects of this class can do the things specified in the interface.

Comment: It can eat up the miles (tumbleweed...)

Comment: some concepts are eating up me head :)

Comment: +1, The Eat() problem exists because csharpbaby's code violates the cohesion rule.

Answer (score 3):

As Lucero points out, you could implement other classes that implement `IRide` without inherting from `Animal` and be able to include all of those in your `IRide[]` array.

The problem is that your `IRide` interface is still too broad for your example. Obviously, it needs to include the `Ride()` method, but what does the `Eat()` method have to do with being able to ride a "thing"?

Interfaces should thought of as a loose contract that guarantees the existance of a member, but not an implementation. They should also not be general enough to span "concepts" (eating and riding are two different concepts).

Comment: Yes I completely agree with,future i will improve my design .

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the difference between abstract classes and interfaces. There is a really good article on that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/abstractsvsinterfaces.aspx).

Comment: No No I am not particular about the differences ,examples to enhance the different way that we can apply interface practically.
Anyhow thanks for your care.

Answer (score 1):

Another great advantage is lower coupling between software components.  Suppose you want to be able to feed any rideable animal.  In this case you could write the following method:

```
public void Feed(IRide rideable)
{
    //DO SOMETHING IMPORTANT HERE

    //THEN DO SOMETHING SPECIFIC TO AN IRide object
    rideable.Eat();
}
```

The major advantage here is that you can develop and test the Feed method without having any idea of the implementation of IRide passed in to this method.  It could be an elephant, horse, or donkey.  It doesn't matter.  This also opens up your design for using Inversion of Control frameworks like Structure Map or mocking tools like Rhino Mock.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can be used for "tagging" concepts or marking classes with specifically functionality such as serializable. This metadata (Introspection or Reflection) can be used with powerful inversion-of-control frameworks such as dependency injection.

This idea is used throughout the .NET framework (such as ISerializable) and third-party [DI frameworks](http://ninject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to grasp the general meaning of Interfaces.

Interfaces are just a contract saying "I support this!" without saying how the underlying system works.

Contrast this to a base or abstract class, which says "I share these common properties & methods, but have some new ones of my own!"

Of course, a class can implement as many interfaces as it wants, but can only inherit from one base class.